# Import Data with Multiple Delimiter for Generic Files

Tags: matlab, import, delimiter

I need to import both space and tabulated delimited data to a matrix style variable or structure, but files vary its formatting, not allowing me to choose a %f %s pre-formatted function as a solution. New columns will be added or removed from a file to another and I don't even know their type.

Excel shows a perfect fit for my data if I open it as a text file and simply choose space and tabulation at the same time as its delimiters.

If you know if is there any import functions for files that allow me to follow Excel's practice or have any idea on how to solve my problem, talk!

An example portion of the text used is found below:

```
loggername  date__________ time________ s1a[m/s]    s1x[m/s]    s1i[m/s]    s1s[m/s]    s2a[m/s]    s2x[m/s]    s2i[m/s]    s2s[m/s]    s3a[m/s]    s3x[m/s]    s3i[m/s]    s3s[m/s]    d1a[°]  d1s[°]  d2a[°]  d2s[°]  h1a[%]  t1a[°C] b1a[hPa]    s4a[m/s]    s4x[m/s]    s4i[m/s]    s4s[m/s]    vxa[V]  bla[V]  bra[V]  [-1=error]  [ser.no.]

TA-48   01/10/2015 00:00:00 5,8 7,1 4,9 0,4 5,7 7,3 4,8 0,4 4,9 5,8 4,1 0,3 161,0   7,0 167,0   8,0 81,0    24,65   1000,0  4,0 4,7 3,3 0,3 12,7    8,0 8,7     C120104

TA-48   01/10/2015 00:10:00 5,8 6,5 5,3 0,2 5,8 6,5 5,1 0,2 5,1 5,6 4,3 0,3 164,0   7,0 171,0   9,0 81,0    24,65   1000,0  4,1 4,8 3,4 0,3 12,7    8,0 8,7     C120104

TA-48   01/10/2015 00:20:00 5,7 6,2 5,2 0,2 5,6 6,2 4,9 0,2 4,6 5,2 3,7 0,3 162,0   7,0 169,0   9,0 82,0    24,55   999,0   3,6 4,3 3,0 0,3 12,7    8,0 8,7     C120104
```

Here the first line represents the titles and units of the variables, being followed by its values in the adjacent lines.

s5a, s5x, s5i, s5s can be new variables in another text file, for example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only space delimited variables were date and time, I decided to separate them after importing the whole tab delimited file.

To do that, I used the `tdfread` fuction, that returns each column as a structure item and proceeded to separate them using a simple `strfind`.

Answer (score 1):

The `dlmread` function without any options will treat both spaces and tabs as delimiters (at least in R2014a):

`mydata = dlmread('myfile.txt');`

However, that will only work for numeric data, and it looks like your file has characters as well. Instead, you can probably do this by using `fgetl` to get a line from the file and then checking for a space or tab using `strcmp`. Something like this inside a loop:

```
line = fgetl(fid);
for k = 1:(length(line)-3);
    if strcmp(line(k:(k+3)),'    ');
        % there's a tab here!
    end
end
for k = 1:length(line);
    if strcmp(line(k),' ');
        % there's a space here!
    end
end
```

Note that this assumes a tab is 4 spaces.

Comment: That worked for me, Brian!
But I decided to use another approach.

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting, I will try using `tdfread` and `strfind` in the future too.